# Setting start page when debugging ASP.NET not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

In my solution explorer I would normally right click on a ASPX file and click on "*Set as Start Page*".  When running the website, it would then start with that page.

All of a sudden, no matter what page I select to start, running the project opens `http://localhost:13713/Default` (which doesn't exist).  Even if I manually type in the path to the ASPX page during the debug session, it'll just return back to `http://localhost:13713/Default`.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened here, but the problem went away after restarting.  The magical restart!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the underlying problem, but one thing to try is to right-click on the root website project file in the Solution Explorer, select the "Property Pages" option then "Start Options" and specify your "default.aspx" (or whatever page you want) as the Specific Page option.

Hope this helps.